# Can Kotlin emit JSR-305 annotations in class files

Tags: types, kotlin, nullable

I'm using Kotlin with https://github.com/vojtechhabarta/typescript-generator to generate TypeScript definitions for my classes that are used in an API.

To preserve nullability information, typescript-generator can use annotations present on fields and methods. It supports arbitrary annotation class names, listed in the build script.

Kotlin, for some reason, annotates nullable fields with `@org.jetbrains.annotations.Nullable` rather than the JSR-305 annotation, `@javax.annotation.Nullable`.

While the JSR-305 annotation has `RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME`, the Jetbrains annotation has `RetentionPolicy.CLASS`, making it unsuitable for introspection by libraries which use Java Reflection to detect annotations.

Is it possible to have Kotlin generate standards-based annotations instead of the JetBrains proprietary annotations?

If not, I'm interested in simple solutions to handle the issue. Perhaps a Gradle plugin that can generate JSR-305 annotations from the JetBrains ones or similar. I would really prefer to not have to double-annotate everything with a `?` and `@Nullable`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Kotlin is designed to emit its own (JetBrains) annotations. This choise was made because [JSR 305](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=305) was never released and there is no legal way for JetBrains to bundle JSR 305 annotations with compiler, since the license on (a dormant) JSR 305 does not allow it. The legal status of the `com.google.code.findbugs:jsr305` maven artifact is likewise murky, since `javax` package namespace is specifically reserved for JSRs.

There are the following possible solutions:

1. Write a custom Gradle plugin that post-processes Kotlin-compiled class files and changes `org.jetbrains.annotations.*` annotations to the corresponding `javax.annotation.*` annotations (`NotNull` to `Nonnull` and `Nullable` to `Nullable`) and changes the corresponding attiributes from runtime-invisible annotations to runtime-visible ones.
2. Patch `typescript-generator` so that it used Kotlin reflection APIs in addition to Java Reflection to get nullablitity information from Kotlin classes. The entry point is for this task is [kotlin](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.jvm/java.lang.-class/kotlin.html) extension of Java `Class` instance that allows to retrieve all the Kotlin metadata.
3. Add [`jackson-module-kotlin`](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-module-kotlin) to `typescript-generator`. This module is using Kotlin's reflection to get all the Kotlin specific information and feed it to Jackson, while `typescript-generator` is using Jackson bean introspection to get its type information, so it might just work.

Comment: Thanks for the ideas. I think the only reasonable one is #3, though unfortunately, it will require patching typescript-generator to use the module to get the metadata, it looks like. It really seems like a major oversight of the Kotlin team, who are quite java-interoperability-minded, to not have a way of determining nullability without writing Kotlin-specific code, though.

Comment: It is a great oversight of Java designers (a billion dollar oversight!) that there is no standard way to get nullability information in Java, so the only way to get it is via Kotlin-specific means.